# How to search for a part of a word in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

I'm looking for something in Gmail like '3456jdjdsnfg'. It is there as I can find it with the exact phrase. But if I search for 3456 it doesn't find anything.

Is there a way I can wildcard the search i.e. 3456*?

Comment: That looks true but doesn't help me

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [Google Scripts](http://www.labnol.org/internet/advanced-gmail-search/21623/) to search for partial matches in Gmail. The script extracts the message body and performs the regex search.

Comment: This is phenomenal, but just last month I received 90,000-ish emails.  The current limit for Google Apps is 50,000 Reads, and I need to search through years of data.  Is there another option?